# Cannot add multiple client certificates with an ASP.NET Core WCF connected service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

Trying to call a soap web service that requires two x509 certificates.

I was able to do this with the ASP.NET Framework project and proxy generated with wsdl.exe tool.

Now generating with new ASP.NET Core proxy generators, we can only set one certificate with service and one for client

```
//wsdl.exe generated code
..            svc.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(settings.TheirCertPath));
            svc.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(settings.OurCertPath));

//dotnet svc utl.exe generated code

var factory = new ChannelFactory<serviceChannel>(binding, endpoint);

factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificate;
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = serverCertificate;
```

Any ideas on why Microsoft would remove the ability to set multiple client certs?

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-mutual-certificates

Your server-side mainly based on the message level security with mutual certificate. Currently it is not supported by ASP.NET Core. Therefore, we could not generate the client proxy class by using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider.

Please refer to the official repository issues:

- https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1354
- https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2766